# Assigning a System.Action to a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net

I have wrote a smalll piece of code to assign an `Action` to a `BackGroundWorker` as a Delegate.

```
public BackgroundWorker GetBackgroundWorker(System.Action doWork)
{
   BackgroundWorker bwk= new BackgroundWorker();
   bwk.DoWork += (sender, args) => { args.Result = doWork; };
   return bwk;
}

BackgroundWorker wk = GetBackgroundWorker(MY_Delegate);
wk.RunWorkerAsync();

public void MY_Delegate()
{
  //DO Stuff
}
```

To make a long story short, I am wondering why method `MY_Delegate` is never entered after I fire the worker with the `RunWorkerAsync` call.
Maybe my assignement syntax around "=>" sucks.
ANyway, I welcome any efficient way to make this work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public BackgroundWorker GetBackgroundWorker(System.Action doWork)
{
   BackgroundWorker bwk= new BackgroundWorker();
   bwk.DoWork += (sender, args) => { doWork(); };
   return bw;
}
```

Assigning doWork to args.Result will not call the DoWork method.

As a side note: the naming of the methods and variables suggests that you do not fully understand delegates, events and lambda expressions.

Comment: Thank You ! I've been messing around with this bug for an hour :-) This a peculiar syntax I am not used to it. I was trying to adapt a Template-based code : `args.Result = (K)doWork((T)args.Argument);`    Actually `args.Result=doWork();` would work, but in this case a have a void delegate so there is no use here. Thanks again !

Comment: Regarding the side note, If I really did understand, I would not ask (stupid) questions :-P More seriously : This is not my "real" code I just tried to write a minimal sample to reproduce the issue I was facing. I was trying to add a "void" delegate feature to this code from a nice blog entry : http://pooyakhamooshi.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-thread-safe-queued.html